# Regex to find specific word starting with a specific char

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

Using Regex, I need to find a word within a string that starts with specific char. The word must be alphanumeric, but may contain underscore (_) within the word. underscore at the beginning and end of the word is not acceptable.

For example I have the following string.

> @word1 Message @@ message @ message @word2_ message @word#3 @_word4 mesagge @word_5

The result should be:

> @word1 @word_5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex will do it!

```
(?<=(^|\s))@([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\w*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})(?=(\s|$))
```

It also matches single letter

Comment: This seems to fail for multiple @ at the begining of the word case. example: @@@@@Word or @@word.

Comment: if you add `+` after the `@` it will allow for multiple `@@@@@`in the answers.  `+` matches one or more

Comment: I want to allow - to be validated. How should I change the regex? e.g. @word-word

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))@(?!_)\w+(?<!_)(?:(?=\s)|$)
```

or

```
(?:^|(?<=\W))@(?!_)\w+(?<!_)(?:(?=\W)|$)
```

depends what you need/want to have infront/behind...

For example if `@word1` in `@word_5 @word1. @word#2 @word*3` should match, considering dot `.` as separator or end of sentence.

Comment: @Anirudha - Code works properly for what is requested. Did you downvote me?

Answer (score 1):

This will work - the bounds (lines 1 and 3) are fairly heavy because `\b`, the word boundary, won't work here since you don't want to match "@word#3", and the "#" character after "d" triggers a word boundary.

```
(?<=\s|^)
    @(?!_)\w+(?<!_)
(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: Also, you're not quite accurate. `\b` does not match the `#` character. It matches *between* `word` and `#`.